# Can the nth projective space be covered by n charts?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

That is, is there an open cover of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ by $n$ sets homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

I came up with this question a few years ago and I´ve thought about it from time to time, but I haven´t been able to solve it. I suspect the answer is negative but I´m not very sure. Also, is there an area of topology which studies questions like this one?

Comment: I'm baffled as to why this got downvoted. I imagine it is straightforward with some alg. top. tool I don't know, but it can't be that easy: $S^n$ is coverable with two copies of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it isn't like compact $n$-folds always need $n+1$ charts.

Comment: A relevant concept here that you can look up goes by “Lusternik-Schnirelmann category”.

Comment: It's not true for $n=1$, at least...

Comment: I think the answer is negative. If a manifold can be covered by $n$ contractible charts then its cup length will be less than $n$. The cup-length for the projective space $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is $n$.

Comment: Thanks! Recently in a course I´ve been learning about the cup product and the cohomology rings of projective spaces, and I suspected they could somehow be used for the problem but I hadn´t thought of cup length.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: This is a standard homework problem, and it's clearly false for $n=1$.

Comment: See the theorem on page 9 [here](https://ptamarov.github.io/PHDCLUB.pdf) for example.

Comment: To put @DavidESpeyer's comment in perspective: the analogous statement in algebraic geometry *is* true: a proper variety of dimension $n$ (e.g. $\mathbf P^n$) cannot be covered by $n$ affine open subvarieties. One argument is to construct a sheaf $\mathscr F$ with $H^n(X,\mathscr F) \neq 0$. The important difference here is that intersections of affine opens are affine, whereas the intersection of contractible open submanifolds need not be contractible.

Comment: To supplement the comment of @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: there is also a difference between the "cover by affines" in AG and the question here: the affine cover versions have few to do with the multiplicative structure, if I understand correct — given the coherent acyclicity of affines, the coherent cohomology could be computed via Čech cohomology. On the other hand, an étale analogue might be much closer to the question here. It is still unclear to me whether the coincidence of local cohomology and the cohomology of the cone is essential in the proof of the question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Expanding on the comment by @user127776, the key reference is Palais, "Lusternik-Schnirelman Theory on Banach Manifolds", Topology 5 (1966),
where it is proved that if $X$ can be covered by $n$ contractible closed sets, then the cup-length of $X$ is strictly less than $n$.

(Here the cup-length is the largest $n$ such that for some field $F$ and some elements $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ in $H^*(X,F)$, we have $c_1\cup\ldots\cup c_n\neq 0$.)

This rules out covering ${\mathbb RP}^n$ with $n$ closed contractible sets, which should suffice here (after slightly shrinking the given $n$ copies of ${\mathbb R}^n$).

**Editing to add:**

More generally, suppose $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space covered by $n$ closed sets $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ with all $H^1(X_i,{\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z})=0 $.  (Equivalently, any (real) line bundle on $X_i$ is trivial.)

**Theorem.** Any line bundle on $X$ can be generated by $n$ sections.

**Proof.** Let $\hat{X}= Spec(C(X,{\mathbb R}))$, so that $X$ imbeds in $\hat{X}$.  Note that:

1. Because $X$ is normal, each $X_i$ is defined by the vanishing of a continuous function, so the $\hat{X}_i$ form a closed covering of $\hat{X}$.
2. By Swan's theorem, the map that takes a vector bundle over $\hat{X}$ to its pullback over $X$ is an equivalence of categories (and likewise with $X$ replaced by $X_i$).

Now because every line bundle on $X_i$ is trivial, so is every line bundle on $\hat{X}_i$.

Because $\hat{X}$ is an affine scheme, a line bundle corresponds to a projective module, which in turn is the image of an idempotent matrix with entries in $C(X,{\mathbb R})$.  A little thought reveals that this matrix can be taken to be $n\times n$.  It follows that any line bundle on $\hat{X}$ is generated by $n$ sections.  Therefore (by the Swan correspondence) so is any line bundle on $X$, as advertised.

**Corollary.** For any $c\in H^1(X,{\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z})$, the $n$-fold cup product $c^n\in H^n(X,{\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z})$ is zero.

**Proof.**  $c$ is the first Stiefel-Whitney class of some line bundle $\xi$.  Let $\phi_\xi:X\rightarrow {\mathbb RP}^\infty$ be the classifying map of $\xi$.  The $n$ sections guaranteed by the theorem provide a factorization of $\phi_\xi$ through ${\mathbb RP}^{n-1}$.  But $H^n({\mathbb RP}^{n-1},{\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z})=0$.

Comment: I look at the paper. Seemingly it is theorem 6.7, and they refer to Bernstein–Ganêa, but I cannot find the later online. Could you please summarize the main techniques?

Comment: @Z. M: The Bernstein–Ganea paper is available [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-5/issue-1).

Answer (score 16):

It seems worth giving the cup-length argument, as it's relatively short and sweet.

Suppose $\mathbb{R}P^n=U_1\cup\cdots\cup U_n$, with each $U_i\approx\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $c\in H^1(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ be the generator.

For each $i$ the inclusion-induced map $H^1(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z}/2)\to H^1(U_i;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is trivial, so by the long exact cohomology sequence of the pair $(\mathbb{R}P^n,U_i)$ there exists a relative cohomology class $c_i\in H^1(\mathbb{R}P^n,U_i;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ whose image in absolute cohomology is $c$. But then by the naturality of relative cup products, $c^n$ is the image of
$$
c_1\cdots c_n\in H^n(\mathbb{R}P^n,U_1\cup\cdots\cup U_n;\mathbb{Z}/2)=0,
$$
and therefore $c^n=0$, a contradiction.

As Aleksander Milivojevic points out in the comments, the relevant area of topology is the study of Lusternik--Schnirelmann category and related invariants.